# Azure DevOps AWS CloudFormation Create/Update Stack task - fails 'stack does not exist'

Tags: azure-devops, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I have a release pipeline configured to use the AWS CloudFormation Create/Update Stack task. The task is configured to use change sets as per below:

[image]

However for some reason the pipeline keeps failing. It fails because it tests for the existence of the stack, finds it does not exist, switches to 'create' mode, but then tests for the existence of a change set, and fails because the change set also doesn't exist?? That makes no sense.

```
2020-12-08T03:54:36.5413925Z Checking existence for stack S2CSalesOrderStack
2020-12-08T03:54:37.5245618Z Test for existence of stack S2CSalesOrderStack returned error: 'ValidationError: Stack with id S2CSalesOrderStack does not exist'.
2020-12-08T03:54:37.5265140Z Stack does not exist, switching to create stack mode
2020-12-08T03:54:37.5267421Z Testing to see if change set S2CSalesOrderStack11 associated with stack S2CSalesOrderStack exists
2020-12-08T03:54:38.3717711Z Test for existence of change set S2CSalesOrderStack11 returned error: 'Stack [S2CSalesOrderStack] does not exist'.
2020-12-08T03:54:38.3724223Z Loading template file from 'D:\a\r1\a\_AWS-S2C-ProcessMessage-CI\serverless-output\serverless-output.yaml'
2020-12-08T03:54:38.3730075Z No parameters file specified
2020-12-08T03:54:38.3731723Z Setting capability CAPABILITY_IAM for stack
2020-12-08T03:54:38.3732908Z Setting capability CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM for stack
2020-12-08T03:54:38.3734631Z Setting capability CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND for stack
2020-12-08T03:54:38.3735285Z Creating CREATE type change set S2CSalesOrderStack11
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5889859Z Change set creation request failed with error: 'undefined' { InternalFailure
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5891500Z     at constructor.extractError (D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:88282)
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5892456Z     at constructor.callListeners (D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:108520)
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5893265Z     at constructor.emit (D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:108230)
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5896438Z     at constructor.emitEvent (D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:183886)
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5897267Z     at constructor.e (D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:179393)
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5898003Z     at r.runTo (D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:185728)
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5898720Z     at D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:185934
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5899455Z     at constructor.<anonymous> (D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:179663)
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5900239Z     at constructor.<anonymous> (D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:183942)
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5901203Z     at constructor.callListeners (D:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.8.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:108626)
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5901689Z   message: undefined,
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5902055Z   code: 'InternalFailure',
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5902486Z   time: 2020-12-08T03:54:46.559Z,
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5903062Z   requestId: '26a7ef25-1e18-4e00-8721-fd07bbd90a53',
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5903486Z   statusCode: 500,
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5903851Z   retryable: true }
2020-12-08T03:54:46.5962341Z ##[error]InternalFailure
2020-12-08T03:54:46.6025994Z ##[section]Finishing: Create/Update Stack: S2CSalesOrderStack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be multiple minor syntax errors in the YAML template itself, such as the way the Ref parameter was used. Unfortunately, the error message doesn't really help to find that as an issue, and additionally the SAM CLI validate command confirmed the template as valid.

Still, with a now fixed and valid serverless YAML template, the pipeline is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot the issue following below steps:

First check if the AWS account that used to create the **AWS Credentials** service connection has `cloudformation:DescribeStacks` and `cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents permissions`. If you used an IAM role to create the AWS Credentials service connection. You need to make sure above permissions are assigned to the role. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html).

Make sure the you select the right `AWS Region`. For CloudFormation is region specific.

Manually delete the the stack that exists, or use the AWS CloudFormation Delete Stack
task to delete the stack before creating.  See below threads for information.

[Stack  does not exist" while creating a new stack](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7340)

[Stack with id does not exist](https://seed.run/docs/serverless-errors/stack-with-id-does-not-exist.html)